# css selector in nested ul

Tags: css, nested, selector

I want to change the style of a nested unsorted list.
original html code has more div tags before but this should demonstrate it:

```css
.ul-style ul
{
  list-style: none;
  color: green; /* should onyl be for the first ul level */
}

.ul-style ul ul
{
  padding-left: 1em;
  list-style: disc;
}
```

```html
<div class="ul-style">
  <ul>
    <li>First Li</li>
    <li>Second Li
      <ul>
        <li>Sub First Li</li>
        <li>Sub Second Li</li>      
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can i change the style of the first "ul" without to change the style  for the second? It allways change the style for the second "ul" too.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<ul>` as a child of a `<ul>`. Also what do you mean by _"without to revert the style for the second"_?

Comment: with revert i mean, if i change for example the font-weight to bold it changes also the font-weight for the nested list to! so if i didn't want the bold tag in the nested element i have to change it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution if i reset/revert the style tags for the second "ul" elements. (In this case the "color" tag)

```css
.ul-style ul
{
  list-style: none;
  color: green; /* should onyl be for the first ul level */
}

.ul-style ul ul
{
  padding-left: 1em;
  list-style: disc;
  color: initial; /* revert/reset the style from first ul */
}
```

```html
<div class="ul-style">
  <ul>
    <li>First Li</li>
    <li>Second Li
      <ul>
        <li>Sub First Li</li>
        <li>Sub Second Li</li>      
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It seems to work for my purpose, please correct me if this cause any other troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out that you improperly nested the list. However, since the outer list has no bullets at all, my suggestion would be to use different list types. Just nest the `ul` inside of the `ol`.

```css
.hwh ol
{
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.hwh ol ul
{
  font-weight: none;
  padding-left:  1em;
  list-style: disc;
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hwh">
  <ol>
    <li>First Li</li>
    <li>Second Li
      <ul>
        <li>Sub First Li</li>
        <li>Sub Second Li</li>      
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: By changing to an ordered list, you are changing the semantics of the list - are you sure the list should be ordered - it looks more like a list of un-ordered links

Comment: @Pete I was suggesting that as a way of separating basic styles. Of course, the very best thing to do in this case is to assign some classes with resets and new unique styles dependent on nesting.You're right, but OP's example is already, technically "ordered" in both cases.